# selectize not working with dynamic knockout options binding

Tags: jquery, select, knockout.js, selectize.js

I am using knockout.js with jquery. The `availableBrands` is defined as:

```
self.availableBrands = ko.observableArray();
```

my ajax request method is :

```
self.loadBrands = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/Electronic/GetBrands',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data,function (i,item) { self.availableBrands.push(item) });
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, status, thrownError) {
                        toastr.error("failed to load Brands.Please refresh page and try again", "Error");
                    }
                });
            }
```

and data I receiving  is:

[image]

**Update:**
I am using knockout options binding with `selectize` plugin as:

```
<select id="select-category" class="demo-default" data-bind="options: availableBrands,
                       value: selectedBrand,
                       optionsCaption: 'Choose brand...'"></select>
```

and js is:

```
$('#select-category').selectize({
                create: true,
                sortField: {
                    field: 'text',
                    direction: 'asc'
                },
            });
```

Now select shows only those options which I hardcoded. It does not show options loaded through ajax.

**Update 2:**

In `loadBrands` function I write
`self.availableBrands.push('ghi');`
and `ghi` is shown in select options. But the data loaded through ajax is not shown.

I changed ajax success to:

```
success: function (data) {
                        $.each((data), function (i, item) { console.log(item); });
                    },
```

and data on console is shown in figure below

[image]

Why data loaded through ajax is not shown in select?

Comment: Just use `$.each($(data),function()`. Convert data into `jquery` object

Comment: you can directly assign than rather pushing check here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26469/ . hope that helps

Comment: Are any errors logged ?

Comment: @guest271314 no error.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao its not working

Comment: Is `self` a `window` object within `success` ?

Comment: @guest271314 no its `var self = this;` at start of function

Comment: @supercool in fiddle you have used hardcode values.My hardcode values are also working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as expected make sure your are referring `jquery` properly .

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.list = ko.observableArray();
    $.each(data, function (i,item) {
        self.list.push(item)
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel([11, 22, 33]));
```

check sample [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26470/) for reference

There is no need to use `$.each` in your this case check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26469/).

Update using `Selectize` plugin check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/26471/)**  .

Try applying `.selectize` in ajax success after options are loaded .

Comment: yes it can happen in that case too . so try applying `.selectize` in ajax success and try . it makes sure it will apply only after options loaded

Answer (score 0):

data is not a jQuery object. You can just use a regular javascript `forEach` statement

```
data.forEach(function(item){ self.availableBrands.push(item)})
```

also `self` may not be correctly set in the callback. You can do the following

```
self.loadBrands = function () {
  var self=self;
  $.ajax({
```